# Node.Js - Jest Testing (Token Problem got 401 "Unauthorized")

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jwt

Hello I'm testing with Jest a project with Node.js
I want to test my functions

```
const userOne = {
_id: userOneId,
name: 'Mike',
email: 'mikey@example.com',
password: '56what!!',
tokens: [{
    token: jwt.sign({ _id: userOneId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
}] }

test('Should get profile for user', async () => {
await request(app)
    .get('/users/me')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userOne.tokens[0].token}`)
    .send()
    .expect(200)
```

})

but I got this error :

```js
● Should get profile for user

expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"

  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:270:12)
  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:11)
  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:175:21)
  at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:133:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get 200 for that endpoint in a REST client with the same Auth token? 401 "Unauthorized" would mean the token is invalid. So you need to check your token. If there is nothing wrong with the token, try below

I believe the request is a require of supertest?

```
const request = require('supertest');

test('Should get profile for user', async () => {
const response = await request(app)
                 .get('/users/me')
                 .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userOne.tokens[0].token}`)
 expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
});
```